# I am not able use the mouse while my test cases are getting executed

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

when I am using actions with selenium, I cannot use mouse. If I use the mouse then the test cases are failing.

Is there a way so that when I am using my mouse these external actions and the mouse actions written in selenium code are not same.

Now it is like I have to sit ideal when my test cases are getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

`Actions` class simulates mouse and keyboard events, so when you mix `Actions` actions with real mouse actions you have actually two mice performing actions in parallel.
I guess the only way to avoid your problem is to run selenium headless. In this case user actions will not be mixed with selenium driver.